# For loop to print a numeric pattern does not print the correct pattern

Tags: java

This is what it should look like

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

8 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 

7 7 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

6 6 6 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

5 5 5 5 5 4 3 2 1 0

4 4 4 4 4 4 3 2 1 0

3 3 3 3 3 3 3 2 1 0

2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 0

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Here's my attempt.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 9;
        int count = -1;
        while (i >= count) {
            int j = i;
            while (j > count) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
                j--;
            }
            System.out.println();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my actual output:

```
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 
9 8 7 6 5 4 
9 8 7 6 5 
9 8 7 6 
9 8 7 
9 8 
9
```

This obviously does not match the expected output. Can someone point out where the mistake is in the code?

Comment: Hine for you : 2 loop!!!

Comment: Break the problem into smaller pieces.  Try and print the first line.  Once you have that, try and print the second line.  Then the third.  After you've printed 3 lines successfully, you should see a pattern that you can implement for the rest of the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Solution that has the right output, but instead of using while-Loops I used for-Loops

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count1 = 9;
        for (int i = count1; i >= 0; i--) {
            int count2 = i;
            if (count1 > count2) {
                int tmp = count1 - count2;
                for (int j = tmp; j > 0; j--) {
                    System.out.print(count2 + " ");
                }
            }
            for (int j = count2; j >= 0; j--) {
                System.out.print(j + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep two outer variables, `counter` and `multiplier`, for the matrix size and repetitions' count respectively:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int counter = 15;
        int multiplier = 1;
        for (int i = counter; i >= 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j<multiplier; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", counter); //using %3d for spacing numbers nicely
            }
            for (int k = counter-1; k >= 0; k--) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", k);
            }
            ++multiplier;
            --counter;
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

For every horizontal line, where *counter* decreases, and *multiplier* increases (9 once on 1st line; 8 twice on the second line, etc.):

- it will first print the `counter`, `multiplier` times;
- it will then fill the rest of the line with `counter-multiplier` number of descending sequence integers, starting from `counter-1`;
- at the end of outer loop's each iteration, a new line is printed.

Output would be:

```java
9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
8  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
7  7  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
6  6  6  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
5  5  5  5  5  4  3  2  1  0
4  4  4  4  4  4  3  2  1  0
3  3  3  3  3  3  3  2  1  0
2  2  2  2  2  2  2  2  1  0
1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have your answer, here are a couple alternatives.

```
String str = "9 8 7 6 5 6 3 2 1 0";
System.out.println(str);
for (int i = 9; i > 0; i--) {
    str = str.replace(i+"",(i-1)+"");
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Or use the `String.repeat`method.

```
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.print((i+" ").repeat(9-i));
    for(int k = i; k >= 0; k--) {
        System.out.print(k + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Java8 stream you can write the code as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .forEach(i -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(j -> {
                
                System.out.print((9- (j < i ? i : j)) + " " );
                
            });
            System.out.println("");
        });
    }
```